# Php DateTime manually select timezone's daylight saving time (DST)

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Is it possible to set the DST of a DateTime Object in Php?

I have a problem for datetimes during the exact moment of change of DST.
In Europe/Paris timezone, the date `2016-10-30 02:00:00` exists twice (as this is the exact moment of change in DST (at 3am it's 2am again)

Let's consider this code:

```
$dateString = '2016-10-30 01:30:00';
$dateBefore = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, new DateTime('Europe/Paris'));
$dateBefore->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$dateString = '2016-10-30 02:30:00';
$dateAfter = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, new DateTime('Europe/Paris'));
$dateAfter->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

`$dateBefore` is '2016-10-29 23:30:00'
`$dateAfter`is '2016-10-30 01:30:00'

So how can I generate the date '2016-10-30 00:30:00' here?

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
$winterTZ = new DateTime('Europe/Paris');
$winterTZ->setDST(false);
$winterDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, $winterTZ);

$summerTZ = new DateTime('Europe/Paris');
$summerTZ->setDST(true);
$winterDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, $summerTZ);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I imagine you've seen from your research on this, timezone handling is a [complicated matter](https://why-cant-we-have-nice-things.mwl.be/requests/datetime-and-daylight-saving-time-transitions), and even more when you're dealing with DST. Your use case is not that clear, but you can achieve what you ask for by adding a 1 hour interval (this is important: not just an *hour*, but an *hour interval*) to the time. Then, the `DateTime` instance will take DST into account and still give you the correct hour (i.e., not "skip" it):

```
<?php
$dateString = '2016-10-30 01:30:00'; // start time
$dateBefore = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
var_dump($dateBefore);
$d = clone $dateBefore;
$d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($d); // 23:30

echo PHP_EOL."------".PHP_EOL;

$dateBefore->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // add one hour without skipping
var_dump($dateBefore);
$d = clone $dateBefore;
$d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($d); // 00:30

echo PHP_EOL."------".PHP_EOL;

$dateString = '2016-10-30 02:30:00';
$dateBefore = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
var_dump($dateBefore);
$dateBefore->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($dateBefore); // 01:30, uses DST
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GZc3j)